# How to design a class with nested property? c#

Tags: c#

how to design a class with nested property. like instance.property1.property2.

please discuss a this with small code in c# as a result class will have nested property.
thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is **not** a discussion forum. Say it after me.

Comment: nested property? You mean Class1.Class2.Property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need whatever the first property returns to have the second property.

```
class Class1
{
    public Class2 property1
    {
        get
        {
            return new Class2();
        }
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public some_type property2
    {
        get
        {
            return some_value;
        }
    }
}
```

Class1.property1.property2 will work here.

The being said, I don't know of any situation where you'd need to *aim* for this syntax. It's usually just a consequence of what your OO structure is. Plus, nesting property calls like that egregiously will incur a small overhead that's not necessary (properties call code every time they're accessed, barring any compile-time optimizations)

Comment: Why would that be ? if i define **Class2** property in **Class1** then within it it could return any of the basic types **Class1.Class2.ID**

Comment: do you really want to new up a Class2 each time the property is called?

Comment: @TimJarvis Just an example. Quickest way to a valid output of property1. Obviously, that'd be horrendous. Unless it was a factory. But then I don't know that you'd want a property to be a factory.

Answer (score 1):

try using nested class with static or constant property:

```
public class A    {
        public class B
        {
            public constant string C = "something";
        }
}
```

then, access: A a = new A(); a.B.C == "something"

Answer (score 1):

Something like that for example:

```
class A
{
  public B B { get; set; }
}

class B
{
  public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
A.B.C = "Something";
```

Comment: so shouldn't you show how B gets constructed? Code as it is written would cause an exception.

Comment: @Tim Jarvis: Of course, it will cause an exception... I am just showing the idea, not implementing a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different classes:

```
public class MainClass
{
   public SampleProp property1 {get;set;}
}
public class SampleProp
{
   public string property2 {get;set;}
}

MainClass test = new MainClass();
var prop = test.property1.property2;
```

Comment: and boom...unless you new up SampleProp somewhere....

Comment: @Tim Jarvis, yes and boom, but it's not test class responsibility to new up fields, because of this I left it to reader to do it in his related item, it's just shows compilation and usage, I should wrote full sample code to do it, but I think there is no need to do this.